# Cargar datos sin Future Builder - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Deseo cargar los datos guardados en una base de datos SQlite en Flutter. No deseo emplear el metodo FutureBuilder ya que este genera un widget y lo que que necesito es realizar algunos procedimientos de validacion.

Estoy usando el código:

```
Future cargarcarros() async {
    final carros = await DBProvider.db.getTodosVehiculos();

    for (int i = 1; i <= carros.length; i++) {
      final db = await DBProvider.db.getVehiculoId(i);
      String placanumero = db.placa.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]'), "");
      String ultimo = placanumero.substring(placanumero.length - 1);
      //shownotification(db.placa);
      return print(ultimo);
    }
{
  }
```

Este código solo me retorna el primer valor de la lista de items de la base de datos.

Como puedo lograr cargar todos los items y que la iteracion funcione de manera correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no quieres usar `FutureBuilder` o `Streams` , puedes hacerlo de la forma más sencilla con `StatefulWidget`.

Suponiendo que estás dentro de la clase State del StatefulWidget :

```
void cargarcarros() async {
    final carros = await DBProvider.db.getTodosVehiculos();
    listado.clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= carros.length; i++) {
      final db = await DBProvider.db.getVehiculoId(i);
      String placanumero = db.placa.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]'), "");
      String ultimo = placanumero.substring(placanumero.length - 1);
      //shownotification(db.placa);
      listado.add(ultimo);
    }

print(listado);
    //con esto refrescas tu widget , ahora podrás usar la variable `listado` 
    setState((){
});
}

final listado = List<String>();
```

Comment: Hice lo que indicaste pero la impresion sigue siendo la misma, solo toma el primer valor de la base de datos.

Comment: imprime listo antes del setState ,,, debería pintar todos

Comment: Acabo de publicar otra respuesta con el codigo modificado, pero sigue sin funcionar, es decir solo imprime el primer registro.

Comment: Borra esa respuesta, solo podias modificar tu pregunta. Por otro lado, no debes usar return ya que ahi terminas el bucle, mira mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: @elreyes, si mi respuesta te ayudó, puedes marcarla como solucionada, de nada :)